# Counting a certain no in list in while loop

Tags: python

I've this variable a as:

```
a = [(1,10),(2,20),(3,30),(4,10),(6,10),(7,20),(8,30)]
```

here in the variable (1,10),1 is the id and 10 is status.
i've to check how many time a single status is coming and get the top3,

```
10 = 3
20 = 2
30 = 2`

x = 0
while (x< len(a)):
        print(a[x][1])
        x+=1`
```

I'm getting it like this but i don't how to count them while in a loop, so please help me out on this

```
10
20
30
10
10
20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `collections.Counter`.

```
import collections

a = [(1, 10), (2, 20), (3, 30), (4, 10), (6, 10), (7, 20), (8, 30)]

print(collections.Counter(x[1] for x in a))
```

This will give you `Counter({10: 3, 20: 2, 30: 2})`.

---

If you want to limit the results then use `most_common`.

```
c = collections.Counter(x[1] for x in a)
print(c.most_common(2))
```

`[(10, 3), (20, 2)]`